# Splitting the app.R code into server.R and ui.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny code in single script, now to deploy this I need to split it into server.R and ui.R. My code is given below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

region <- c("Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region3")
market <- c("MarketA", "MarketB", "MarketC", "MarketA")
submarket <- c("SubmarketX", "SubmarketY", "SubmarketZ", "SubmarketX")

mod.selection <- data.table(
  Region = region,
  market_name = market,
  submarket_name = submarket
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(Feature = character(0), Value = numeric(0)))
  
  observeEvent(input$select_region, {
    markets <- mod.selection$market_name[which(mod.selection$Region == input$select_region)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_market", choices = markets, selected = markets[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_market, {
    submarkets <- mod.selection$submarket_name[which(mod.selection$market_name == input$select_market)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_submarket", choices = submarkets, selected = submarkets[1])
  })
}

#Ui function----
ui <- 

  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         selectInput("select1", label = h4("Data Type"),
                                     choices = list("Unit" = 1),
                                     selected = 1),
                         verbatimTextOutput("value1")
                  ),

                    column(3,
                           selectInput("select_region", label = h4("Region"),
                                       choices = mod.selection$Region,
                                       # choices = list("Central" = 1, "West" = 2, "East" = 3),
                                       # choices = NULL,
                                       selected = 1),
                           verbatimTextOutput("value2")
                    ),
                    
                    column(3,
                           selectInput("select_market", label = h4("Market"),
                                       choices = unique(mod.selection$market_name),
                                       verbatimTextOutput("value3")
                           )),
                    
                    column(3,
                           selectInput("select_submarket", label = h4("Sub Market"),
                                       choices = NULL),
                           verbatimTextOutput("value4")
                    ),
                  
                  ),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                  ),
                  
                  mainPanel(
                  )
                )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I struggle to access the mod.selection from the server and ui codes. Do I have to read the data in both the codes?
This is a sample code, and in my original code, I also have a lot of other data.
What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to actually divide the app in at least 3 files.

1. `ui.R`

```
ui <- 
  
  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
            fluidRow(
              column(3,
                     selectInput("select1", label = h4("Data Type"),
                                 choices = list("Unit" = 1),
                                 selected = 1),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value1")
              ),
              
              column(3,
                     selectInput("select_region", label = h4("Region"),
                                 choices = mod.selection$Region,
                                 # choices = list("Central" = 1, "West" = 2, "East" = 3),
                                 # choices = NULL,
                                 selected = 1),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value2")
              ),
              
              column(3,
                     selectInput("select_market", label = h4("Market"),
                                 choices = unique(mod.selection$market_name),
                                 verbatimTextOutput("value3")
                     )),
              
              column(3,
                     selectInput("select_submarket", label = h4("Sub Market"),
                                 choices = NULL),
                     verbatimTextOutput("value4")
              ),
              
            ),
            
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
              ),
              
              mainPanel(
              )
            )
  )
```

2. `server.R`

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(Feature = character(0), Value = numeric(0)))
  
  observeEvent(input$select_region, {
    markets <- mod.selection$market_name[which(mod.selection$Region == input$select_region)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_market", choices = markets, selected = markets[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_market, {
    submarkets <- mod.selection$submarket_name[which(mod.selection$market_name == input$select_market)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_submarket", choices = submarkets, selected = submarkets[1])
  })
}
```

3. `global.R` for common operations.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

region <- c("Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region3")
market <- c("MarketA", "MarketB", "MarketC", "MarketA")
submarket <- c("SubmarketX", "SubmarketY", "SubmarketZ", "SubmarketX")

mod.selection <- data.table(
  Region = region,
  market_name = market,
  submarket_name = submarket
)
```

If you are using Rstudio then you'll see the "Run App" button on top of each of these files to run the application.

[image]